# Circumstances for accessing Folder in C drive in Server PC (Through LAN)

Tags: vb.net

What are the circumstances for getting full access a folder in C drive in Server PC, so that without any single probelm people can access it remotely (Via LAN)?

There are number of windows PCs which are connected via centralized LAN. Among of them one is act as Server Pc. My problem is that one pc is not able to read/write to the Server PC C drive folder. At same time other PCs are easily aaccessing the server pc folder.

Server PC Win 10 (Firewall full off)
C:/ProgramData/My Folder (Full Share Access)

User PC 1 Win 7 (Firewall ON)
No Problem to get access server-pc/c/programdata/my folder

User PC 2 Win 7 (Firewall ON)
No Problem to get access server-pc/c/programdata/my folder

User PC 3 Win 7 (Firewall off)
PROBLEM to get access server-pc/c/programdata/my folder

Error Message:
"Logon failure: unknown user name or bad password."

when user pc 3 is trying to hit c drive in server pc above error message is comming.
Please help me.

Comment: Does the one that can't connect have the same user name as a user on the server PC but with a different password.  Try creating a mapping to the share and choose to specify user name & password in the mapping and use credentials you know to work on the server PC.

Comment: PC that can't connect having different username and password from its server pc. Mapping is successsful and can access the desire folder. Here is the background i have made a vb.net project that need to read and write that particular folder. when i run my application and as it hit the desire folder the above said error comes. ("Logon failure: unknown user name or bad password")